# Flarum URL is redirecting to Wordpress 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've Wordpress on my main domain. I wanted to include [Flarum](http://flarum.org/) as a sub-folder. So, my folder structure will be like

```
wp-contents/
wp-includes/
index.php
forums/ --Flarum
forums/.htaccess
forums/index.php
forums/...
```

Here, I could access forums using url: `abc.com/forums`. But when I tried to access other URLs of Flarum, it redirects me to Wordpress 404 error page. For example. `abc.com/forums/login` redirects me to `Page Not Found` on `abc.com`

I would highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: That's because there's no 'login' directory in 'forums'. Wordpress thinks you're making a direct request to it if the directory (or in this case subdirectory) doesn't exist. This is what the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` in the root .htaccess file is all about.

Comment: So how would I fix the issue.. Flarum has its own `.htaccess`

Comment: You can start by posting your code.

Answer (score -1):

Write this htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```